# I need to know if this is load bearing. Removing old tub and new tub is larger. Need to cut studs out to make room

Tags: load-bearing

[image]
Ive purchased a new tub thats larger than the existing.  I tore out the wall to make room.  Im not sure if this is a load bearing wall or not.  Any help appreciated!

Comment: The double stud with a spacer, holding up a short double top plate sure looks like load bearing, but you need an engineer or architect to look to be sure. And you may have to expose a bit more of the framing.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if it’s load bearing because: 1) spaced double stud, 2) no header across opening,

1) Load bearing POSTS tend to be solid posts or built up solid posts...not spaced apart studs.

2) Load bearing WALLS tend to be continuous and would require a header across the opening.

If you can remove some ceiling gypsum board and look above the wall, you can easily determine if it’s load bearing. Just make sure no studs or posts rest on top of the wall.

Also, if you can check under the wall and see if there is a wall, beam, post, etc. directly under the wall, then it probably is load bearing...if not, you’re good to go.